# SSRS merging columns based on vales

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a matrix report in SSRS and currently have a column for each day. e.g day 1, 2, 3,4,5 and so on. I would like to merge those columns for the first 5 days so days 1-5 in column and name it <5. I have been working on expressions using if statements and switch but still not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to following steps:

1. Open dataset properties and under Fields, create a new calculated field (Let say name of the new field is **YourDayFieldName**_New) and put following expressions:

   =IIf(Fields.YourDayFieldName.Value<=5,”<5”, CSTR(Fields.YourDayFieldName.Value))
2. Now in your matrix, do the column grouping on this calculated field (**=Fields! YourDayFieldName_New.Value**)

Comment: thanks for that I have this as my expression for calculating business days

Comment: What are the dates or day returns your above mentioned function? Can you post few samples?

Comment: so I have created a calculated field which calculates days business days from a field called date received. I have now created a matrix which has those days received in the column group. so now I get dynamic columns like 1,2,3 or even like 3,4,6 depending on the calculation. I want to be able to merge those first 5 days in other words group them in a column "<5 days".

Comment: Use this expression in you matrix column group =IIf(code.Weekdays(Fields!DATE_RECEIVED.Value,Today())<=5,”<5”, CSTR(code.Weekdays(Fields!DATE_RECEIVED.Value,Today())))

Comment: do I add this to the column group expression? how can i do it for lets 6-10 days and so on? thanks for ur help so far

Comment: 0-5,15-30,31-60,61-90